# why sed replace + redirection deletes my file?

Tags: bash, sed, io-redirection

I am using sed to search and replace two strings in a file in bash (GNU sed)

This is the file after

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 websync www-data 4156 mar 27 12:56 /home/websync/tmp/sitio-oficial/sitios/wp-config.php
```

here is the command I run

```
sed 's/www-test/www/g' /home/websync/tmp/sitio-oficial/sitios/wp-config.php > /home/websync/tmp/sitio-oficial/sitios/wp-config.php
```

and the result

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 websync www-data 0 mar 27 13:05 /home/websync/tmp/sitio-oficial/sitios/wp-config.php
```

**EDIT:** If I don't redirect sed's output, then I got the correct output. If I redirect to a new file, all works ok.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is normal. you can't read and write to the same file in a pipeline like this. (this will fail with other utilities than sed).

Use the in-place flag `-i` instead:

```
sed -i 's/www-test/www/g' /home/websync/tmp/sitio-oficial/sitios/wp-config.php
```

Comment: accepted for pointing out that **this will fail with other utilities**

Comment: Yes, I was waiting 5 minutes, according to stackoverflow. Thanks!

Comment: Or you use the following command: `BUFFER="$(cat FILENAME)"; echo "$BUFFER" | SOME_COMMAND > FILENAME`

Beware though, this is not what environment variable are used for, generally. Wrap it in a for loop, and you've got mass file processing, in place!

Answer (score 5):

sed reads your files in as a stream and outputs a stream as well. As soon as you perform the redirection into your file the contents are overwritten, and since that file is being read as a stream, it hasn't even started being read by sed yet. When sed does start reading the file it is empty so it finishes immediately with no output.

Use `-i`, to do an in-place edit, instead:

```
sed 's/www-test/www/g' -i /home/websync/tmp/sitio-oficial/sitios/wp-config.php
```

Answer (score 2):

The redirection opens the file for output, truncating it. This happens simultaneously to `sed` opening it for reading, so `sed` sees the truncated version. You should redirect your output to a different file to avoid clobbering your input, or use `sed`'s in-place editing mode instead of using redirection:

`sed 's/www-test/www/g' -i /home/websync/tmp/sitio-oficial/sitios/wp-config.php`